# android how to remove bracket form database retrive value

Tags: android

my database return my value with bracket how do i remove bracket form string  and save without bracket value in my array string?? help me pelase help me value is properly getting i just want to remove bracket around my string and save in ArrayList Meal_groupid

```
           static ArrayList<String> Meal_groupid = new ArrayList<String>();
        Meal_groupid.add(mCursor2.getString(mCursor2.getColumnIndex("meal_group_id")));


        value is = "[AT]";



       i did  like this 


           String formatedString = "[ABC]"

                    .replace("[", "")   //remove the right bracket
                    .replace("]", "");

    Log.i("Formating Stirng",""+formatedString);

   Meal_groupid.add(mCursor2.getString(mCursor2.getColumnIndex("meal_group_id")).replace("[", 
                      "").replace("]", ""));
              Log.i("MEalGroup ID",""+Meal_groupid);



    in     logcat  Formating Stirng    ABC


             MEalGroup ID
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get set or get the string you can do a replace to remove the [ and ].

For example:

```
Meal_groupid.add(mCursor2.getString(mCursor2.getColumnIndex("meal_group_id")).replace("[", "").replace("]", ""));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i did this Meal_groupid.add(mCursor2.getString(mCursor2.getColumnIndex("meal_group_id")).replace("[", "").replace("]", "")); still not working

Comment: In that case are you sure the brackets are stored within the database and the brackets aren't arriving when you are reading the value of what is stored in your Meal_groupid object. You can use the same replace method when you are also retrieving the value from your Mail_groupid object. Give it a go on where you are trying to read the value and see if it fixes

Comment: check my updated question simple stirng work finebut araysting not work

Comment: Your question isn't very clear in the new output, It looks as if you are expecting something to be written to logcat after MEalGroup ID but there isn't anything being output afterwards, but if this is the problem this isn't the same as the question that you are removing the [ or ] from the string. I assume ``Meal_groupid`` is some sort of array so you wouldn't be able to just print the root object to the log cat and instead would have to get an element from the array. Possibly Meal_groupid[0] but without seeing how that is declared that is a guess. Could you clarify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge "[" is considered as **regex** so you need to replace string using

```
mString.replaceAll("\\[", " ");
```